# An error occurred while creating the AVD. See idea.log for details

Tags: react-native, android-studio, android-emulator, emulation, android-virtual-device

I am having the Error while I am trying to create an emulator on Android studio, 
"An error occurred while creating the AVD. See idea.log for details" 
[See idea.log ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAYHP.png)

[Idea.log.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZKNS.png)

[ReactNative Error (No emulator)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKWik.png)

[I can't choose the CPU/ABI on the AVD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvBDP.png)

However, when I start AndroidStudio as a Root, I am actually able to create AVD but still having an error running it:

[AS Root Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJVqE.png)

please note that I am trying to run a ReactNative app and I have downloaded all the required packages and plugins successfully. 
*using Linux Ubuntu latest v

Comment: Please show some last lines of 'idea.log'.